# Registering 2 activities to receive images, it doesn't work when sharing from Google Photos app

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, google-photos

Let's say in my app, users can make posts & send messages to other users, & I want to register my app as a component among those appears in the Share-via picker when sharing either text or an image, I'm defining my 2 activities in my `AndroidManifest.xml` as follows (like [this official example](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#ExampleFilters)):

```
<activity 
    android:name=".SharePostActivity"
    android:label="MyApp (Post)">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".ShareMessageActivity"
    android:label="MyApp (Message)">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**When sharing text**, this **works perfectly fine**, where I see 2 icons of my app among available apps for sharing text, named `MyApp (Post)` & `MyApp (Message)`,

**Problem happens when sharing an image**, because only one icon appears with the second defined label in the manifest (which is `MyApp (Message)`), and actually it opens the first defined activity in the manifest (which is `SharePostActivity`),

So, how to show the 2 options when sharing an image (just like what happens when sharing text)?

*(I've tried on an emulator running Nougat & a real device running Oreo)*

**----- Update -----**

I've found that this weird behavior happens only when sharing images from **Google's Photos** app, but everything works fine when sharing an image from other apps!

Comment: Have you tried to add a specific mimetype, e.g `image/jpeg`instead of `image/*`

Comment: Yes, but issue still exists

Comment: I think it's a problem with Google photos, I've noticed the behaviour as well

Comment: Just use a single dialog activity for the intent and then when the user open selects your app, the dialog activity shows some choices of activity that can handle the request

Comment: @NizaSiwale , but I want to have 2 options in the system's picker for a better UX, Twitter & Instagram are already having more than one icon in the system's picker, which means that it is doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some investigation leads to a solution: each of your `intent-filter` must contain an `android:label` which points to a **resource**, not a hardcoded string.

```
...
<intent-filter android:label="@string/first_value">
...
```

Different `Activities` must have different labels, so in your case the Manifest should look like

```
<activity 
    android:name=".SharePostActivity"
    android:label="@string/my_app_post">
    <intent-filter
        android:label="@string/my_app_post">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter
        android:label="@string/my_app_post">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".ShareMessageActivity"
    android:label="@string/my_app_message">
    <intent-filter
        android:label="@string/my_app_message">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter
        android:label="@string/my_app_message">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Really!! you must be kidding me! .. It actually worked!  .. I've tried every single combination possible (including using labels in the filters), but never thought that using a **Resource** for the labels would be the solution (usually I change strings to a resource last thing before making my commit) .. this is missed up man  , 
Thanks a lot man .. actually, you deserve more bounty than just 50 